# Register and enqueue style.css custom theme

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-script, css

I'm trying to create a custom theme for wordpress, I created all these file:

style.css 
index.php
function.php
footer.php
header.php
page.php
single.php
front-page.php

This is the code of my style.css:

```
/*
  Theme name: La Pizzeria
  Theme URI: http://www.matteoschiatti.it
  Author: Matteo Schiatti
  Author URI: http://www.matteoschiatti.it
  Description: Theme for Restaurants
  Version: 1.0
  License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
  License URI: http://www.gnu.org/license/glp-2.0.html
  Tags: restaurant, mobile first, responsive, pizza
  Text Domain: lapizzeria;
*/

body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.test {
  color: red;
}
```

This is the code of my function.php:

```
<?php

function lapizzeria_styles() {

  //Adding stylesheets
   wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0');

  //Enqueue the style
   wp_enqueue_style('style');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lapizzeria_styles');
```

This is the function of my header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>La pizzeria</title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
 <span class="test">fdsafdsafdsafsdafsdafsdafdsafsa</span>
```

And in the other files there is inside this code:

```
<?php
  get_header();
?>

<?php
  echo "la pizzeria";
?>

<?php
  get_footer();
?>
```

I cannot understand why the style.css doesn't work, the header is embedded properly because I can see the title of the page so I think there is some problem with the function in the function.php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function.php should be functions.php.